# autowareauto.git causes permission error during ADE installation. Are additional permission rights required?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

git clone --recurse-submodules git@gitlab.com:autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto.git

Causes error: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

During ADE installation on Ubuntu 18.10. with Docker 19.03.6

#autoware

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357387/autowareauto.git-causes-permission-error-during-ade-installation.-are-additional-permission-rights-required?/) by [jpalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/56691/jpalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems a problem of ssh in gitlab. Please add the ssh key in your gitlab account. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

---

Originally posted by [TakaHoribe](https://answers.ros.org/users/42648/takahoribe/) with karma: 181 on 2020-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jpalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/56691/jpalo/) on 2020-07-17**:
Thank you for the response. The problem was solved by installing ade via http instead of ssh. It was indeed an ssh/gitlab problem. the ssh key should have worked, too.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-07-18**:
Please remember to accept the answer if your question was answered (the checkmark under the score buttons).